# Animação div com Jquery nao reconhece teclas

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <title></title>    

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>


        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).keypress(function(x){
            if(x.wich == 13 || x.keyCode == 13){
                var div = $("div");
                div.animate({height: '300px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
                div.animate({width: '300px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
                div.animate({height: '100px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
                div.animate({width: '100px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
            }
          });
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pessoal, esse código está funcionando apenas com tecla enter (keycode 13). Se eu mudar pra outra tecla, como 39 por exemplo, e apertar, ele não executa a ação.

Answer (score 5):

Troque o evento de `keyPress` para `keyDown` que funciona perfeitamente:

Obs.: O certo é `x.which` e não `x.wich:`

A diferença básica é que o `keypress` reconhece a inserção de caracteres, ou uma mudança no input, semelhante ao evento `input`.

Como diz a [documentação do JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> This is similar to the keydown event, except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events. Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(x) {
    if (x.which == 39 || x.keyCode == 39) { // right arrow
      var div = $("div");
      div.animate({
        height: '300px',
        opacity: '0.4'
      }, "slow");
      div.animate({
        width: '300px',
        opacity: '0.8'
      }, "slow");
      div.animate({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: '0.4'
      }, "slow");
      div.animate({
        width: '100px',
        opacity: '0.8'
      }, "slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Como a seta não faz *print* de nenhum *char*, ela não é reconhecida no `keypress`.

Comment: show de bola cara, obrigado !

Comment: Por que não `keypress`?

Comment: @RafaelMafra, editado :)